# Set background color of summary row of extjs grid

Tags: extjs, background-color, summary

Enable summary grid;

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            features: [{
                ftype: 'summary'
            }],
```

Add a summaryType config to the columns you need;

```
columns: [{
    dataIndex: 'name',
    text: 'Name',
    summaryType: 'sum',
...
```

custom summaryType looks like;

```
dataIndex: 'subtotal',
text: 'SubTotal',
summaryType: function(records){
    return 100*100;//custom function
}
```

Simple css addition to change background color of the summary row of extjs grid;

```
.x-grid-row-summary {
    background-color: #efefef;
}
```

Custom SummaryRender;

```
{
     dataIndex: 'count',
     text: 'Count',
     summaryType: 'count',
     summaryRenderer: function(value, summaryData, dataIndex) {
         return (value && value>100)?"<font color='red'>"+value+"<font>":value; 
     }
},
```

Comment: you have any question or posting about changing bgcolor of  summary row of grid?

Answer (score 2):

Just add below css style

```
.x-grid-row-summary {
    background-color: #efefef;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for asking something 2 years later. Hoping to get a response. How can I change the summary row background color dynamically? The above would change the background color for all the summary rows I suppose. I would like to change the color depending on some condition for each summary row.

Comment: u can use: "summaryRenderer: function ()" to manipulate summay cell as well as row, just set a css class to this record element